# Chart.js - How to parse array of objects as the dataset for Pie Chart

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

I have Chart.js and chart data in this format:

```
chartData = [
  { data: 2, label: 'Label 1' },  
  { data: 10, label: 'Label 2' },  
  { data: 40, label: 'Label 3' },
];
```

How can I parse my data to get a classic pie chart like this:

[image]

I have tried to follow the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html) but it is not available.

This is my template:

```
<canvas baseChart
        [datasets]="chartData"
        [type]="pieChartType"
        [options]="pieChartOptions">
</canvas>
```

and here is my ts:

```
chartData = [
  { data: 2, label: 'Label 1' },  
  { data: 10, label: 'Label 2' },  
  { data: 40, label: 'Label 3' },
];

public pieChartOptions: ChartConfiguration['options'] = {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      position: 'top',
    },
    datalabels: {
      formatter: (value, ctx) => {
        if (ctx.chart.data.labels) {
          return ctx.chart.data.labels[ctx.dataIndex];
        }
      },
    },
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Pie Chart Data Structure](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/doughnut.html#data-structure) docs, it mentions that:

> datasets need to contain an array of data points. The data points should be a number,

You need to follow its structure as below:

```
public pieChartDatasets = [
  {
    data: [300, 500, 100],
  },
];

labels = [
    'Red',
    'Yellow',
    'Blue'
];
```

Well, you can transform your `chartData` to match its structure:

```
pieChartLabels: string[] = [];
pieChartDatasets: any[] = [];

this.pieChartLabels = this.chartData.map((x) => x.label);
this.pieChartDatasets = [
  {
    data: this.chartData.map((x) => x.data),
  },
];
```

And in the `baseChart` HTML element, pass the `pieChartLabels` to `[labels]` attribute.

```
<canvas
  baseChart
  [datasets]="pieChartDatasets"
  [type]="pieChartType"
  [options]="pieChartOptions"
  [labels]="pieChartLabels"
>
</canvas>
```

[Demo (CustomPieComponent) @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-hj6r1x?file=src/app/custom-pie.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks Yong, I have fingered this just hoped there is a way to pass the array of objects. Thanks